# Why dynamic Casimir effect does not appear in static gravity field?

Tags: general-relativity, vacuum, equivalence-principle, casimir-effect

Dynamic Casimir effect tells us that a constantly-accelerated mirror should emit radiation due to interaction with vacuum. Following principle of equivalence, a similar mirror placed in static gravitational field should emit either.

So will planet which surface is covered with a mirror emit any radiation and if no, why not?

Comment: The equivalence principle is local, true only in the limit. Locally the field of the planet is close to uniform, which is equivalent to a uniform acceleration. In the case of uniform acceleration the mirror does not emit (I think).

Comment: @MBN "In the case of uniform acceleration the mirror does not emit" - where did you read it? Actually dynamic Casimir effect talks about any acceleration.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood what you mean by the DCE, it just needs the mirror to be moving at relativistic speeds and acceleration is not required.

Comment: @Anixx, I am not sure, that's why I said 'I think'. Why do you think there will be radiation in the case of uniform acceleration? The paper I was looking at is Fulling-Davies (1976)

Comment: @John Rennie "it just needs the mirror to be moving at relativistic speeds and acceleration is not required." - in that case the linear momentum of the moving mirror would change and the mirror will change its speed due to interaction with vacuum (this contradicts the principle that all inertial frames are equal)

Comment: @ MBN indeed, there is second derivative of speed there in their formula. Still some sources claim it just need to be accelerated at constant rate (some sources even claim that Hawking radiation is a case of dynamic Casimir effect because the event horizon can be interpreted as a mirror.

Comment: @Anixx it may be that they make assumptions that lead to that conclusion, which in general are not needed, and there is radiation in the case of uniform acceleration. I cannot tell.